# How to use glDrawArrays to display cube in JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am new in with Java OpenGL (JOGL). I want to display a 3D cube in JOGL.

I have vertex array information with me.

```
double vertices[]= {
    0 0 0,
    0 0 1,
    0 1 0,
    0 1 1,
    1 0 0,
    1 0 1,
    1 1 0,
    1 1 1,
};
```

I want to use `glDrawArrays()` to display it. Since I have display a model having a **huge amount of vertices.**

The display method is given below.

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    gl.glEnd();
}
```

I need to use `GL_TRIANGLES` or `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` only and `not GL_QUADS`.

If anyone knows how to use `glDrawArrays();` in **JOGL** please help me. I want JOGL syntax and not opengl.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want JOGL syntax and not opengl." ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `glDrawArrays();` then you have to create a VBO (Vertex Buffer Objects) or a VA (Vertex Arrays). If you're after speed, then choose VBO, though they require some extra lines of code to be made!

The best way I think I can explain how to create a VBO to you, is by giving you an example!

#### VBO Example

Here is a little example of a VBO storing Vertices and Colors for a Triangle and rendering it and also how to delete it!

#### Creating the VBO

This is the code where you create the actual Vertex and Color Buffer and bind them to the VBO.

```
int vertices = 3;

int vertex_size = 3; // X, Y, Z,
int color_size = 3; // R, G, B,

FloatBuffer vertex_data = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices * vertex_size);
vertex_data.put(new float[] { -1f, -1f, 0f, });
vertex_data.put(new float[] { 1f, -1f, 0f, });
vertex_data.put(new float[] { 1f, 1f, 0f, });
vertex_data.flip();

FloatBuffer color_data = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices * color_size);
color_data.put(new float[] { 1f, 0f, 0f, });
color_data.put(new float[] { 0f, 1f, 0f, });
color_data.put(new float[] { 0f, 0f, 1f, });
color_data.flip();

int vbo_vertex_handle = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertex_handle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

int vbo_color_handle = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_color_handle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

You can of course add more Vertices and Colors to the `vertex_data` and `color_data` if you want to! But always remember that the amount of vertex data, need to match with the amount of color data and vice versa!

**Important:** Only create the VBO(s) once, and only update them when necessary! Don't create them for each frame, since them you will end up with a frame-rate worse than when using immediate mode for rendering!

#### Rendering the VBO

This is the code you need to call, to render the VBO.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertex_handle);
glVertexPointer(vertex_size, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_color_handle);
glColorPointer(color_size, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices);

glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

#### Deleting the VBO

Then when you're done with the VBO and you don't need it anymore, you can delete it by doing the following.

```
glDeleteBuffers(vbo_vertex_handle);
glDeleteBuffers(vbo_color_handle);
```